# How do I save an attachment from an Outlook email retaining the date time stamp of the attachment

Tags: vba

I am trying to use a script and rule in Outlook to automatically file an attachment. It works but instead of using the attachment's date time, it uses the current datetime.
Here is my script:

```
Public Sub saveFedhealthstatement(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat
dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm")
Dim subject
subject = itm.subject

saveFolder = "f:\filing\fedhealth"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments

        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & subject & objAtt.DisplayName


        Set objAtt = Nothing

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You mean the attachment's `Date Modified/Created` Time as shown in windows explorer?

Comment: Yes I would like to retain the Date time stamp as shown in explorer.

Comment: I don't know a direct way to do it. When Outlook saves/creates an attachment then it always takes the current date/time. I can think of 2 alternatives though. `1` Extract the date/time of the email and then save the attachment with that inn the file name. For example If the file is ABC.EXT then save it as ABC 06_10_2013_110900.EXT `2` One unconventional way that I can think of is to get the email's date/time and then change the system time and date and then download the attachment. Once it is downloaded then change the system time back to normal. Though I am not in favor of the 2nd option.